# How long should Neo4j database seeding take?

Tags: database, neo4j, seeding

I need to seed a Neo4j database, but I'm not sure how long seeding should take. After seeding, the database will have roughly 20K nodes and maybe 3-4 million relationships. I understand that there are **tons** of variables to consider, but should something like this take a few minutes, an hour, multiple hours, or days? I'm just looking for a very rough estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 20k nodes in less than a second. For the relationships that will depend upon the indexes you create and the queries you use. That will likely fall into the minutes range, depending on the complexity of those queries.